# Change marker icon using Jmapping

Tags: jquery

I'm using jmapping plugin for displaying places in a google map. How do I change the default icon for all icons, I read GM Api docs but I can't understand how to do it?

Thanks!
PS I don't have any code live just in my local.

Answer (score 3):

had this same problem today. I accomplished by ...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#map').jMapping({

    category_icon_options: function(category){

       if (category.match('your-cat-name')) {

              return new google.maps.MarkerImage('path to your image');

           } 


         }

    });

 });
```

Probably not the most elegant solution. I have a different graphic for each point, so you could leave it or extend it depending on the category name.

Answer (score 3):

On the page that shows your map, put the following in your javascript map code that starts with:

```
$('#map').jMapping({
```

You want to include a blank category matching icon option line like such

```
category_icon_options: {
  '': {color: '#E8413A'}
```

In StyledMarker.js, find the following lines of code:

```
getURL: function(props){
  var _url;
  var starcolor_=props.get('starcolor');
  var text_=props.get('text');
  var color_=props.get('color').replace(/#/,'');
  var fore_=props.get('fore').replace(/#/,'');
  if (starcolor_) {
    _url = bu_ + 'd_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin_star|';
  } else {
    _url = bu_ + 'd_map_pin_letter&chld=';
  }
```

Change the last line between the single quotes to your desired icon code with options.  For example:

```
} else {
    _url = bu_ + 'd_map_xpin_icon&chld=pin_sleft|bank-dollar|52B552';
  }
```

This will give you a green marker with a dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to accomplish alternate icons, but I can change the color using this [example](http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/examples/category_options.html).

```
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="map-side-bar">
  <div class="map-location" data-jmapping="{id: 1, point: {lng: -122.2678847, lat: 37.8574888}, category: 'market'}">
    <a href="#" class="map-link">Berkeley Bowl</a>
    <div class="info-box">
      <p>A great place to get all your groceries, especially fresh fruits and vegetables.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="map-location" data-jmapping="{id: 2, point: {lng: -122.4391131, lat: 37.7729943}, category: 'restaurant'}">
    <a href="#" class="map-link">Nopalito</a>
    <div class="info-box">
      <p>The best authentic Mexican restaurant in San Francisco.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="map-location" data-jmapping="{id: 3, point: {lng: -122.4481651, lat: 37.8042096}, category: 'museum'}">
    <a href="#" class="map-link">Exploratorium</a>
    <div class="info-box">
      <p>A hands-on museum of science, art, and human perception in San Francisco.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding jquery call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#map').jMapping({
    category_icon_options: {
      'restaurant': {color: '#E8413A'},
      'museum': {color: '#465AE0'},
      'default': {color: '#7CDF65'}
    }
  });
});
```